# Error while calling a method

Tags: java

I have my code in two seperate source files in the same project. I am trying to call a method from one of them into the other, but it keeps throwing the error `cannot find symbol - method Person()`.

Main class - SchoolClasses

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SchoolClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Person();
    }
}
```

Second Class-Person

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person extends SchoolClasses {
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;

    public void Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        firstName = firstName;
        lastName = lastName;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return lastName + "," + firstName;
    }
}
```

Am I calling the method wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code. I've added inline comments wherever applicable.

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) // Constructor shouldn't have a return type
{
    // Use this keyword because otherwise firstName = firstName; just shadows your instance variables
    this.firstName = firstName; 
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Also you need to create a new `Person` object like this in your `main()` method, as you do not have a default constructor in your `Person` class.

```
Person person = new Person("firstName", "lastName"); // Because the constructor in your class takes 2 parameters
```

As a side note, I really do not see the use of `Person` extending `SchoolClasses`. You should re-think what exactly you're trying to do with the 2 classes.

Comment: How am i supposed to write my public Person then? writing it how I did with no return types I cannot specify both first and last name. I have it now as public Person(firstName lastName) because when i try to add a comma it cuts it after the comma and will not continue.

Comment: @user3301604 - You should not have return type for the constructor but you need to have the data type for the parameters in the constructor. `public Person(String firstName, String lastName)` as given in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `Person` constructor correctly in your `main`. You want this instead:

```
Person person = new Person("First", "Last");
```

However, your `Person` constructor in the class shouldn't have the `void` keyword for it to be seen as the constructor:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
```

With the `void` in there, the compiler does not interpret the `Person(String firstName, String lastName)` as the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: in main(): Person p = new Person("f name", "l name");

Answer (score 0):

There is always a standard Constructor,
still you will have to call

```
new Person();
```

or use the Constructor with you parameters First and Lastname like:

```
new Person("first","last");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said - there is no method `Person()` in `SchoolClasses`. If you want to instantiate a `Person` with name "Hello World", the `new` operator is your weapon of choice: `Person p = new Person("Hello", "World");`.